# как ускорить перебор?

Tags: c++, циклы, перестановка

условие - есть 11 пронумерованных шариков от 0 до 10, я достаю случайным образом по 1 шарику и смотрю их номера, если номер хотя бы одного шарика совпадает с номером вытягивания(считаем от нуля до 10) - комбинация считается победной(пример: 2 0 1 3 5 4 6 7 9 8 10 - победная, так как совпали числа 3  6 7 10).

есть кусок кода, он пересчитывает циклом по +1, этот код считает в 11ричной системе, и считает он где то 256 дней, собственно надо как-то ускорить.
(прибавляет к последнему разряду 1 и проверяет, если проверка успешная то записывает +1 к сумме правильных вариантов, снова прибавляет 1 к последнему разряду, каждый разряд - переменная)
код написан максимально просто - без массивов, всяких подпрограмм и прочего, задействованы только кейсы(это есть один из кейсов) циклы for, условия if и cin cout.
ответ хотелось бы получить так же написанным максимально просто как этот отрывок.

```
for (int z = 0; z <= 3; z++) {
        z--;
        if (z != 3) {
            j++;
            if (j == 11) {
                j = 0;
                i++;
                if (i == 11) {
                    i = 0;
                    h++;
                    if (h == 11) {
                        h = 0;
                        g++;
                        if (g == 11) {
                            g = 0;
                            f++;
                            if (f == 11) {
                                f = 0;
                                e++;
                                if (e == 11) {
                                    e = 0;
                                    d++;
                                    if (d == 11) {
                                        d = 0;
                                        c++;
                                        if (c == 11) {
                                            c = 0;
                                            b++;
                                            if (b == 11) {
                                                b = 0;
                                                a++;
                                                if (a == 11) { 
                                                    k++;
                                                    a = 0;
                                                    if (k == 11) {
                                                        k--;
                                                        z + 100;
                                                        break;
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (k == 10 or a == 9 or b == 8 or c == 7 or d == 6 or e == 5 or f == 4 or g == 3 or h == 2 or i == 1 or j == 0) {
            if (a != b and a != c and a != d and a != e and a != f and a != g and a != h and a != i and a != j and a != k) {
                if (b != c and b != d and b != e and b != f and b != g and b != h and b != i and b != j and b != k) {
                    if (c != d and c != e and c != f and c != g and c != h and c != i and c != j and c != k) {
                        if (d != e and d != f and d != g and d != h and d != i and d != j and d != k) {
                            if (e != f and e != g and e != h and e != i and e != j and e != k) {
                                if (f != g and f != h and f != i and f != j and f != k) {
                                    if (g != h and g != i and g != j and j != k) {
                                        if (h != i and h != j and h != k) {
                                            if (i != j and i != k and j != k) {
                                                summ++;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << summ << endl;
    break;
```

Comment: *есть кусок кода, он пересчитывает циклом по +1 все варианты когда число стоит под таким же номером что и само число, этот код считает в 11ричной системе* — а теперь то же самое, только по-русски, внятно изложите условие задачи, а то понять ваше *число стоит под таким же номером что и само число* наверняка труднее, чем написать программу...

Comment: добавил более менее понятное условие

Comment: Что вы считаете?

Comment: [Беспорядок (перестановка)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA_(%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0))

Comment: Мда... Написано максимально просто)

Comment: я понимаю что есть определенные формулы для перестановок и подсчета их количества, но ведь и путем прибавление по 1 можно получить такой ряд чисел в котором встретятся все те уникальные значения перестановок. вопрос в том как ускорить код не меняя идею

Comment: @JMonster А можно вопрос, зачем???

Comment: `z + 100;` - что здесь происходит?

Comment: Перебор *11^11* комбинаций на компьютере 3ГГц потребует около 95 секунд (*11^11/(3 * 10^9)*). Это в предположении что на порождение следующей комбинации требуется одна инструкция ассемблера. Для каждой комбинации делается *11* проверок на совпадение и *(10 * 9/2) = 45* проверок на неравенство. Грубо говоря 56 элементарных операций. *57 * 95 = 5415* - больше полутора часов. Это очень и очень оптимистичная оценка, на деле всё будет хуже. Вы действительно хотите оптимизировать именно ваш перебор? Его можно оптимизировать алгоритмически. Его можно вовсе не делать если прибегнуть математике.

Comment: *Мда... Написано максимально просто)* Как по мне, максимально просто — это проверка 11! перестановок. Примерно 40 миллионов. Ну никак не день и даже не час... Простите, ну очень интересно — вы реально что-то считали 256 дней, или это просто оценка? P.S. Вот, тупой перебор — меньше секунды: https://ideone.com/irOdBW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение реализует вычисление числа порядков в соответствие с формулой включения-исключения.

Идея: допустим у нас arr[0] = 0 - это фиксированная точка, тогда мы точно знаем, что любые перестановки в остальной части массива, будут подходящим для нас решением. Теперь продолжим, пусть arr[1] = 1 - это фиксированная точка, соотвественно перестановки во всей остальной части массива будут подходящим решением, но вот беда, множества этих решений пересекаются, соответсвенно нам нужно это пересечение отнять. Идём дальше arr[2] = 2, то же самое, только теперь у нас проблема в том, что уже пересечения пересекаются и мы отнимаем это пересечение пересечений два раза, соответсвенно нам нужно его прибавить. И т.д. Вообщем, примерно как-то так можно сформулировать идею стоящую за формулой включения-исключения.

Формула включений и исключений: https://www.matburo.ru/ex_tv.php?p1=tvvi

Беспорядки (см. Задача Эйлера): https://www.matburo.ru/tvart_sub.php?p=dear_problem

```
#include <iostream>

int calc(int n) {
    int res = 0;
    for(int t = 1, k = n; k > 0; --k) {
        res += k & 1? t : -t;
        t *= k;
    }
    return res;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << calc(11) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Насколько я помню, порядки равны разности перестановок и бепорядков. Правильно? Это значение и находит функция calc. Я её, правда, чуток изменил сейчас.

Comment: Похоже на реализацию метода включения-исключения. Действительно, без пары слов объяснения выглядит как колдовство.

Comment: @MBo Это и есть реализация метода включения-исключения...